# decrypt local ssl traffic (MacOS)

Tags: ssl, https, sniffing

I am trying to reverse engineer a protocol which uses HTTPS exclusively.

On Windows I was using [oSpy](http://code.google.com/p/ospy/) to view the plaintext of local SSL packets, but for MacOS I have not been able to find an equivalent.

Is anyone aware of a tool which allows you to view the plaintext of HTTPS communications on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) can do this according to the description.

It might also work with [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/), there is a section [on the support page](http://tuffcode.com/support.html#support7) about it.

Comment: Thx, Charles seems to work well.

Comment: HTTP Scoop is no longer available